Upwork API error -Warning: 299 Accessing API with invalid key
I get this error message : <message>Warning: 299 - "Accessing API with invalid key"</message>
with any request I send through Postman, I also send the access token with it as a bearer token,
I am pretty sure the api and authorization are correct.
testing the api in postman
I use this URL to get the access token:
https://www.upwork.com/ab/account-security/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(REDIRECT_URI)}
and I send the auth token through Postman
as here: enter image description here

You don't show how you send the authorization headers, so we can't know whether you did it correctly. (When you do, mask the actual key!)

did you read the documentation? Upwork uses OAuth Authentication. https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=node#authentication_oauth-20

@MoFarid             yeah, I followed these steps, but They don't have a section listing this code error 299, and I saw many people arguing about this issue that their APIs used to work in the past but now they get this error message
so yeah i am pretty sure it's not the authentication issue

update:
turned our test APIs were shutdown by upwork, you have to use GraphQL as alternate
